# Swift - Unable to add data to UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode-storyboard

Learning Swift and Storyboards, I'm attempting to create a View of repeating cells (UITableView).

So far I have created a view with a UIView, linked to a UITableView with a UITableViewCell inside. The issue I'm having is my cells are not displaying "woof" as per below.

My View Controller looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId") as! MyListViewCell
        cell.myLabel.text = "woof"
        return cell
    }

}
```

After some research, I believe I don't need to register:

`myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")`

as it's already linked as an outlet successfully

but I thought I may need to do delegate and datasource like so:

```
myTableView.datasource = self
myTableView.delegate = self
```

but I received: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

I am attempting to use MVVM which I *think* is meant to only use the one ViewController. Am I meant to be using a UITableViewController instead?

I have verified that my cell identifier is set correctly in the storyboard.

Comment: can you show us full crash log? or may be your `myLabel` is not linked with outlet in your cell

Comment: There is no crash log, I have confirmed that the identifier on the cell is set to `myLabel`

Comment: for cell identifier you have to set `cellId` in storyboard identifier field. check this link https://imgur.com/bLIExXB

Answer (score 1):

This error in your case can be related to the missing connection between UITableView in a storyboard and your IBOutlet myTableView.

Concerning the UITableView.register(_:forCellIdentifier:) method, when you are creating a cell in UITableView in a storyboard then this method is called by UIKit when loading the storyboard. You should call this method when you have created a custom UITableViewCell subclass in code or Xib file.

Setting delegate and dataSourceDelegate can be done in a storyboard file without creating an IBOutlet in a view controller. Just select Table View and go to the connections inspector and drag a delegate and a datasource delegate to the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check if you have connected properly on storyboard(Outlets,identifier everything).
Secondly, if nothing works try disconnecting and connecting the Outlets again.